# Good database for superfast storage of large amounts of financial data?

Tags: database, database-design

I'm storing large amounts of financial data for options. Recommendations for a database to store this data?

**Edit**

- "large amounts" is 1GB initially, scaling up to around 100GB at some point in the future.
- Fine with either commercial and open source.
- Developing with Microsoft Visual Studio 2010 and C#.
- Latency/retention periods: need to store streaming realtime data in such a way that I don't lose any of the data coming in (probably about 10KByte/sec maximum data to store). Querying can be performed outside of market hours, so speed of querying is not an issue.

Comment: What is "large amounts"? 1MB? 1GB? 1TB? 1PB?

Comment: What commercial/development constraints - open source/COTS/supported/unsupported? Machine/OS limitations? Plug and play/development platform? Latency/retention periods? ...... And how long is the piece of string anyway?

Comment: if you really are talking about 'large' amounts of data, then there are other considerations such as the backup and restore story, availability of hardware, number of drives, DAS versus SAN etc

Comment: 100GB is not particularly large.

Comment: and 10KByte/sec is not particularly fast. It starts to look as if any of the DBs in @CesarGon's link are likely contenders.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since this is a Microsoft-based project the obvious choice is Microsoft SQL Server, which has very good integration with C# and Visual Studio.

100GB is not large.

Comment: Ended up going with Microsoft SQL Server. According to my expert friend, for the amount of data I am dealing with I will not run into scaling issues in the future.